# Visual Studio 2022 Snippets not working for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I did a fresh install of Visual Studio 2022 v17.0.0 (.NET 6.0) and created a new WebAssembly project. Tried editing Counter component but none of the snippets work for C#.

Typing <kbd>cw</kbd> is supposed to bring up `Console.WriteLine` but nothing happens, tabbing does nothing but insert tabs. Tried several other snippets and same results. If I enter `Console.` I should get suggestions popping up but I get nothing.

I tried doing a repair installation but didn't fix the problem. Any suggestions as to what else I can try to fix. Thanks

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report than a Q&A.

Comment: in my case I used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031055/snippets-doesnt-work-on-visual-studio-2022

Answer (score 23):

Most likley it is functioning but I found that VS 2022 made som changes to the default behaviour.

Make sure that when you type your phrase in the the document that it is appearing on top of the suggestion box.
[Example showing suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmZcW.png)

If not press `ctrl + alt + space`. Try again.
[Example not showing suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXFCt.png)

If you are experiencing that the phrase you are typing is not default selected when you try to tab out your snippet you may want to **change** your **IntelliSense behaviour** from **'Include snippets when ?- Tab....' to 'Always include snippets'**.

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense > 'Always include snippets'
```

Best of luck, fingers crossed, godspeed and all that. =)

Comment: This works. Have no idea how it got turned off. I have not touched it but it got set to Never on an update or something else (keypress?). Anyway, 'Always include snippets' worked.

Answer (score 3):

For me only enabling `Always include snippets` didn't work. With the Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.4.3 I had to disable the `Show new snippet experience (experimental)` option in the `Tools->Options->Text Editor->IntelliSense`. There is no need to restart VS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `tools`/`options`/`texteditor`/`advanced` and check that `default intellisense completion mode` is `automatic`.

Then I have the `cw` snippet appearing, and it is inserted after typing twice tab:

[image: cw snippet intellisense]

2. With `ctrl+k`, `ctrl+b` check that your snippets are present; if there is a problem here, you may have a [problem with your snippet file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/troubleshooting-snippets?view=vs-2022).

Other remarks:

3. Do not log in as user as it may rewrite you parameters.
4. If a repair does not work, deinstalling then installing again VS will give a cleaner install.

Comment: Yes that is already set to Automatic. Problem persists

Comment: @user1068557 I installed VS2022 in a VM without registering any user (it may rewrite your parameters if different). Do you repro your problem in that case ?

Comment: @user1068557 please check with ctrl+k,ctrl+B that the `cw` snippet is here also

Comment: I ran installCleanup.exe -f for a complete removal of VS and reinstalled VS but same problem. ctlr+k ctrl+b shows the cw snippet. When I type cw I don't get the tooltip popping up like the screenshot above shows so there is nothing to tab select. Other snippets like prop and for do not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but managed to get things working again.  In the Code Snippets Manager (`CTRL + K` `CTRL + B`) I noticed my snippets folder had the same name as another folder ("Visual C#").  I removed my folder from Code Snippets Manager, renamed it in File Explorer to be unique when in the Code Snippets Manager, then added it back in to Code Snippets Manager.

I then had to restart my Visual Studio 2022 before it recognised my snippets.

Following that, it seems I can edit my snippets without having to restart VS.  I'd say VS 2022 has a problem with the initial recognition of the custom snippets folder.

Comment: Thanks but I haven't added any custom snippets, I can't get the snippets that come installed with VS to work

Answer (score 0):

If you re-add the snippets and restart Visual Studio it works.

In my case, if I copied the folder in the picture and opened in explorer it seems like the folder **doesn't exist**. But if I press "Add" and navigate to this folder it **does exist** and I can add the default snippets again.

[image]