# Snippets don't work on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

Version: 17.0.1 Professional

I can't use any snippet. I'm having a hard time, especially on Razor. Help please

[image]

Comment: Please specify "doesn't work". What happens if you try? Did it work on older versions? Does it still work on older versions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The new Razor editor in VS2022 does not have full feature parity with the older one from previous versions; it does however have new features specific to newer ASP.NET Core runtime features.  There is still continued effort in achieving feature parity, so please send feedback to help the team prioritize which features are in highest demand.

You can turn toggle back to the old editor in the HTML editor settings (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Advanced -> Use legacy Razor editor for ASP.NET Core)
[image: Tools/Options settings]

Edit:
[This blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio-2022/) calls out several of the missing features.  As mentioned above, the team is working on making most of them work again, but that is largely prioritized based on the feedback being received through the [Razor Tooling github](https://github.com/dotnet/razor-tooling/issues) or the VS Feedback system (the team looks at both).

Comment: Thanks, this was a dealbreaker for me in upgrading to VS2022 (it also breaks JavaScript snippets).

This article from 1-DEC-2021 mentions some missing features in the new Razor engine, several of which are real productivity hits to me.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio-2022/

Comment: The issue : https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/6397