# Autocomplete not working in html files in VS 2022

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-2022

I have previously used VS2019 and switched to VS2022 just a couple of days ago (both Community edition on Windows 10 Pro).

Now, autocomplete is not working for me in cshtml files. Same problem as described here: [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/qtcnnd/autocomplete_not_working_in_html_files_in_vs_2022/)

If I type `div` and press TAB nothing happens, in VS 2019 it was automatically changed to: `<div></div>`.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "type div and press tab" is technically a snippet, not autocompletion.  Snippets are not currently working on the new Razor editor in VS2022, but the feature is currently being worked on.  If you want to switch back to the old Razor editor, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031055/snippets-dont-work-on-visual-studio-2022/70044638#70044638).