# Is there a drag and drop function for css, JS and bootstrap in asp.net visual studio 2022?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, linker, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to drag my css folder and drop into my html code in asp.net visual studio 2022 and it's not working though it works for visual studio 2019. Please I need help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snippets doesn't work on Visual Studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031055/snippets-doesnt-work-on-visual-studio-2022)

Comment: This is a known (temporary) takeback in the new Razor editor in VS2022.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio-2022/#known-issues-roadmap