# How do I get my Angular text Colorized in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

This is a strange issue, but likely an easy one for someone who has done it before.

I just installed Visual Studio 2022. Opening a file, I immediately noticed that my Angular code is no longer purple on my `.cshtml` pages.

This was super helpful in Visual Studio 2019.

Here's what it used to look like in VS 2019...

[image]

And here's what it looks like in VS 2022...

[image]

I have ReSharper, but it's installed in both and I'm not even sure that's where this is coming from.

I'm fairly certain I installed all the same (or similar) extensions, but still can't figure out what is doing this.

I'd love to have my purple code colors back!

Any help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried disabling your extensions in 2019 to see if any of them affect this colouring? Take a look in the `Fonts and Colors` option in VS to see if you can spot that nice purple highlight.

Comment: yes i def tried this, but couldn't find what was doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a product regression, there's a feedback item open [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/double-curly-braces-highlighting-not-wor/1591952).

The longer story is that it's related to the [new Razor editor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio-2022/) in VS2022.  The legacy editor would highlight these somewhat blindly, because they do slightly different things in different front-end frameworks, but the syntax was largely consistent.  The new editor doesn't (yet) do that.

Until the issue is fixed, you can change back to the legacy editor following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70044638/25071) but you'll miss out on any new features being added for Razor development.

Comment: brilliant! not good news for me, but glad i'm not going crazy...